# Firemonkey: How to iterate through all forms in the application using TScreen.Forms

Tags: c++, forms, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I am attempting to iterate through the forms I have open in my application.  I have found the documentation for [FMX.Forms.TScreen.Forms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Forms.TScreen.Forms), which looks like it can be used to accomplish my goal.  However, I am confused on how I am supposed to use it.

At first I tried this in a function within my form's CPP file:

```
ShowMessage( Forms::TScreen::FormCount );
```

This produced the error `'Member TScreen::FormCount cannot be used without an object'`

I figured that to mean that I need to attempt to access this property from my form, or from the global `Application` variable.  I tried both

```
this->Forms...
Application->Forms...
```

and

```
this->TScreen...
Application->TScreen...
```

However, neither `Forms` nor `TScreen` exist within either of these objects.

How do I go about accessing `Forms.TScreen.Forms`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error gives you a clue:

> Member TScreen::FormCount cannot be used **without an object**

`TScreen` is a class, not an object.  `FormCount` is not a static member of the class, so you need an object instance of the `TScreen` class.  And such an object is provided for you - the global `Screen` object:

```
ShowMessage( Screen->FormCount );
```

This is stated in the documentation:

[FMX.Forms.TScreen](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Forms.TScreen)

> There is a global variable, [`Screen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Forms.Screen), of type `TScreen`, which is instantiated for use by any application with a GUI. Use [`Screen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Forms.Screen) to obtain information about the current state of the screen in an application.

[FMX.Forms.Screen](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Forms.Screen)

> extern DELPHI_PACKAGE TScreen* Screen;

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works well:

```
ShowMessage(Screen->FormCount);
```

`Screen` is a global object, like `Application`. The compiler said that `FormCount` is not static method or smth.